# Am I being billed on each Firebase Authentication instance?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have many activities in my app that require the user to undergo Firebase Authentication. For example in the home activity and numerous other activities:

```
FirebaseAuthentication.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

If they have been authenticated when they first open the app are they being authenticated again when they start a new activity within the app? Am I being billed each time? If so, do I have any alternatives? I'd like to avoid passing strings through intents if possible. Note: Firebase disk persistance has been enabled on the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no billing involved to sign in a user with Firebase Authentication, ever.

The [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) suggests that the only pricing is for phone auth verifications.

Comment: Ah, I think I misinterpreted what phone auth verification meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No getCurrent user is saved in your local device after authentication whenever you call firebase auth.getCurrentUser he will check from your local device